# how to display text in MultiCell() in fpdf?

Tags: fpdf

I have a problem in FPDF. I want to use MultiCell() to display a text. my code is as follows:

```
$syarat .='<ol><li>aaa</li>
<li> bbb
<li> ccc</li>
<liddd</li>';

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',7);
        $pdf->SetX(10);
    $pdf->MultiCell(190,4,$syarat,0);
```

//but the problem is it display also with ,

tags. How to appear numbering instead of ,

tags?. Thank You

Comment: How did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

In FPDF did not support the HTML tag ,you have to write it by yourself.

1) if you want to do like this: you can try with HTML->PDF http://html2pdf.fr/

2) You can do with multiple cell Please learn from this exampel
http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script3.php

If you need help from the example ,Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

FPDF supports HTML but you need to use a script such as: http://fpdf.org/en/script/script53.php

This one claims that it has `full support for lists <li>`.

To make the numbers appear, you can always do that manually, for example:

```
$syarat .='<ul>
     <li>1. aaa</li>
     <li>2. bbb
     <li>3. ccc</li>
     <li>4. ddd</li>
</ul>';
```

Other scripts are available [here](http://fpdf.org/en/script/index.php), but I don't see another one that supports `<LI>` tags.